# Issues using Azure Active Directory (ADAL) with Aurelia

Tags: azure-active-directory, aurelia, adal

I've added [Azure Active Directory Library (ADAL)](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js) to an Aurelia CLI 0.31.3 project and I appear to be out of my element.

[Here is my repository.](https://github.com/YardGnomeNinja/aureliaWithADAL)

The issues that I'm running into are:

- Accessing the "Reports" page for the first time allows you to log in.
  When it returns from the Azure AD sign-in, the Aurelia app reloads
  twice.
- Clicking "Log In" when on the "Home" page allows you to log
  in. When it returns from the Azure AD sign-in, the URL contains
  "/token_id=XXXX" and the Aurelia router errors stating "Route not
  found".

Some notes on the project:

- There are only two views. "Home" does not require authentication. "Reports" does.
- *./src/app.ts* , *./src/authorizeStep.ts* , and *./src/sessionState.ts* ,  should be the only places any authentication code exists.

Any insight as to how to resolve these would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@juunas probably has a working solution, but my take on this would have been slightly different.

The error pretty much says it: "Route not found". Aurelia is trying to match "token_id" to a route while that value should probably be ignored after your `AuthorizeStep` used it.

It may suffice to simply add it to your home routes like so:

```
{ route: ['', 'home', 'token_id'], name: 'home',  moduleId: 'resources/views/home/home', nav: true, title: "Home" },
```

If it still doesn't match, you could add a wildcard as well: `token_id*`

That will solve the router error. You haven't mentioned whether the authentication itself works or not - if the router error was the only problem, this should do the trick.

### EDIT

To follow up on my comment, as an alternative to using a separate view/viewmodel as a route you can also do this:

```
config.map({
  name: 'logInRedirectCallback',
  navigationStrategy: (instruction: NavigationInstruction) => {
    const token = instruction.getWildcardPath();
    // [...] do magic / pass the token to wherever it's needed

    instruction.router.navigateToRoute(""); // or any page that makes sense after logging in
  },
  route: 'token_id=*',
});
```

I have not tested this so you may need to tweak the exact place of that wildcard. This works under the assumption that token_id is matched as part of the path, not part of the query. But the general idea is to just intercept that token, process it however you need to and then go to some existing page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I was able to successfully authenticate from the get-go, sorry for not making that clear. The trouble was with how the callback was being triggered. This does solve the router throwing an error, however it doesn't cause the ADAL client to be notified that authentication was successful. Because of this, I'm unable to determine authentication state without refreshing the page.

Comment: Fair enough, in that case you either need to add an `AuthorizeStep` that matches on that particular route and notifies the client, or a bit simpler (but slightly less "clean") you could simply make a special `auth.ts+html` or something similar. Route `token_id` to that, and in the code for that particular page, grab the token from the `params` in `activate()` and pass that on to the client. (I might add a proper example later if you want, in a bit of a rush now)

Comment: I think you may be on to something with the auth.ts+html suggestion. I hadn't considered that before. I believe that will solve the issue of having to configure multiple return routes, which I'd really like to avoid, and I can re-route the user to their requested route once authentication returns. Unfortunately, I'm not actively working on this project at the moment due to new priorities, but I'll mark this as the accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: Sure thing! In case you haven't yet, I'd recommend looking into this plugin: https://github.com/aurelia-contrib/aurelia-open-id-connect - if the plugin itself doesn't scratch the itch, looking at its code should also give you some solid examples of handling authentication directly in the route pipeline. It's really neat.

Comment: Great! I'll take a look. Thanks!

Comment: Only bad thing is that Azure AD is not fully OIDC compliant. The v1 endpoint does not use the `scope` parameter, but uses a `resource` instead. So that library may or may not work :/

Comment: Yep. Which is why I emphasized the suggestion to look at its code if the plugin itself didn't work. OP doesn't even need the library because it's only a tiny part of his flow that's not working. The main thing about that plugin is that it utilizes pipeline steps in a very neat way which is worth learning from.

Comment: Added a distilled example.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience with Aurelia, but here are the steps I took to make it work at least partially.
Hopefully you can get it working fully :)

First, I enabled verbose logging for ADAL.JS in sessionState.ts:

```
constructor(aureliaConfiguration, sessionState) {
    this.aureliaConfiguration = aureliaConfiguration;

    if (!this.authContext) {
        this.authContext = new AuthenticationContext(
            {
                cacheLocation: "localStorage",
                clientId: this.aureliaConfiguration.get('azureADApplicationId'),
                tenant: this.aureliaConfiguration.get('azureADTenant'),
                postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin
            }
        );
        Logging = {
            level: 3,
            log: (msg) => console.log(msg)
        }
    }

    this.appName = this.aureliaConfiguration.get('name');
    this.appApiKey = this.aureliaConfiguration.get('api.key');
}
```

Then I found ADAL giving an error about invalid state.
I noticed the URL was not really what it should be.
Usually the Id token is in a fragment, e.g. `#id_token=asdasdasdas...`.
Of course this is just the framework's feature of showing pretty client-side routes.

Turns out there is a way to tell Aurelia not to modify URLs with hashes, while still using the normal routing links:

```
configureRouter(config: RouterConfiguration, router: Router): void {
    this.sessionState.router = router;

    config.title = 'Aurelia';
    config.options.root = '/';
    config.options.pushState = true;
    config.options.hashChange = false;
    config.map([
        { route: ['', 'home'], name: 'home',  moduleId: 'resources/views/home/home', nav: true, title: "Home" },
        { route: ['reports'], name: 'reports',  moduleId: 'resources/views/reports/reports', nav: true, title: "Reports", settings: { auth: true } }
    ]);
    config.addAuthorizeStep(AuthorizeStep);
}
```

I added one line there: `config.options.hashChange = false;`.
After doing that, ADAL logged a successful authentication.

But I did say the solution was partial.
The login button still says "Log in".
After a page refresh it does change to "Log out", but that is one thing that needs to be fixed.
Also, clicking on "reports" does cause a redirect to AAD, but it specifies the redirect URL as `http://localhost:9000/reports`.
The problem is that we would need to configure every single client-side route as a reply URL for this to work.

So instead of using the full URL, you will need to use just the domain in `authorizeStep.ts`:

```
if (!user) {
    this.sessionState.authContext.config.redirectUri = window.location.origin;
    this.sessionState.authContext.login();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately, neither part of the solution improved the situation. I was able to successfully authenticate from the get-go, sorry for not making that clear. The trouble was with how the callback was being triggered. As you state, the partial solution is moderately successful, unfortunately the ADAL client doesn't get notified that the auth was successful. Also, changing 'window.location.href' to 'window.location.origin' means that the callback doesn't return the user to the page they were attempting to access. It always returns to 'home'.